# Proper structure for Food class with data from json

Tags: json, swift, data-structures

I am building a Food class used in a tableview with data feed from a food database API.

What will be the proper structure of this class? This of course would be trivial if the nutrition value (e.g. calories) didn't change with measurement but it does so each nutrient is dependent on it.

The json looks something like this (https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=f&format=json&api_key=DEMO_KEY):

```
"report": {
    ...
    "food": {
        ...
        "name": "Cheese, cheddar",
        ...
        "nutrients": [
            {
                ...
                "unit": "kcal",
                ...
                "measures": [
                    {
                        "label": "cup, diced",
                        "eqv": 132.0,
                        "eunit": "g",
                        "qty": 1.0,
                        "value": "48.87"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "cup, melted",
                        "eqv": 244.0,
                        "eunit": "g",
                        "qty": 1.0,
                        "value": "90.33"
                    },
```

My initial idea was to access the data first then structure the class later. This is what i have done:

```
static func getFood (withSearchString search: String, completion: @escaping ([Double]) -> ()) {

    let url = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=f&format=json&api_key=\(key)"
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        var value: [Double] = []

        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                    if let report = json["report"] as? [String: Any] {
                        if let food = report["food"] as? [String: Any] {
                            if let nutrients = food["nutrients"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                                for dataPoint in nutrients {

                                    if let measures = dataPoint["measures"] as? [[String: Any]]{

                                        for dataPoint2 in measures {
                                            if let value2 = dataPoint2["value"] as? Double {
                                                value.append(value2)
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            // pass the instance as an argument to the completion block accessed in the nutrition class
            completion(value)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

At the moment, this just extracts the value of each nutrition on each measure of it. Can anyone give guidance as to how to structure the app, then i can feed the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what your question is exactly, but what I would do to parse that JSON is create different models like this:

```
struct Measure: Codable {
    let label: String
    let eqv: Double
    let unit: String
    let qty: Int
    let value: String
}

struct Nutrient: Codable {
    let unit: String
    let measures: [Measure]
}

struct Food: Codable {
    let name: String
    let nutrients: [Nutrient]
}
```

Then you can just decode your JSON into these models using the JSONDecoder like this

```
try JSONDecoder().decode(Food.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Your answer was exactly what i was looking for. I couldn't think of a way to set up the structure of the class with the information from the json. Given that, is there a simpler way for me to decode my json avoiding the pyramid of doom as i have shown in the code above?

Comment: Yes, with the last line. As long as your models conform to the Codable protocol and your properties have the same names as the keys in your JSON, the JSONDecoder should be able to convert your data.

Comment: This guide is super useful, if you want to learn more about how the JSONDecoder works: http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/

Comment: Thanks a bunch. You have saved me a lot of time trying to work this out myself.